# How to add a drop-down list for data entry in Azure DevOps Server 2022?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards, azure-devops-server-2022

I've recently switched process models from XML to Inherited, to allow for easier customization of Work Item Types, etc.

Under the old XML model we could modify, for example, a PBI's `Effort` field to [create a pick list of numbers](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/755/tfs-2010-edit-workitem-type-definition-power-tool) for easier data entry. I'm not seeing how to do this with the Inheritance model:

[image]

The documentation for doing so under XML is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-modify-field?view=azure-devops-2022&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#customize-a-pick-list), but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent under Inheritance.

[image]

For example, here's the `Effort` field in my XML-modeled collection:

[image]

Is it possible to modify a PBI to this extent under the Inheritance model? If so, how does one go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done using in-built methods. So say Microsoft Support Engineers.

Tossing together this clunky workaround wasn't pleasant, but at least it accomplishes the goal (I say that because I loathe working in JavaScript).

Install the TamperMonkey extension in your browser and load up the script below. Replace `example`, `host`, `collection` and `project` in the URLs with your own values. Edit a PBI and feel the love.

Note that this only addresses PBIs and their *Effort* and *Business Value* fields under the Scrum template; that's all I needed to cover at this point. The script will need to be adjusted to support other Work Item Types and fields.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         PBI PickLists
// @namespace    https://example.com/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://host/collection/*
// @icon         none
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    "use strict";

    // Your code here...
    function setSelected(item) {
        item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
        item.classList.add("selected");
        item.style.backgroundColor = "#deecf8";
        item.style.border = "1px solid #c7dff3";
    }

    function clearSelected(item) {
        item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
        item.classList.remove("selected");
        item.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        item.style.border = "1px solid white";
    }

    function getFibonacciList(textBox, container) {
        var pickList = document.createElement("ul");
        var items = ["1", "2", "3", "5", "8", "13"];

        pickList.setAttribute("role", "listbox");
        pickList.classList.add("items");
        pickList.style.marginBottom = "0px";
        pickList.style.marginTop = "0px";

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = document.createElement("li");
            item.setAttribute("role", "option");
            item.setAttribute("aria-posinset", i + 1);
            item.setAttribute("aria-setsize", items.length);
            item.setAttribute("data-id", i);
            item.style.padding = "3px";
            item.style.cursor = "pointer";
            item.textContent = items[i];

            if (item.textContent == textBox.value) {
                setSelected(item);
            } else {
                clearSelected(item);
            }

            pickList.appendChild(item);
        }

        pickList.childNodes.forEach(function(item) {
            item.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
                setSelected(item);
            });

            item.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
                clearSelected(item);
            });
        });

        return pickList;
    }

    function clearList(textBox, uniqueId) {
        var container = document.getElementById(uniqueId);

        if (container) {
            var items = container.querySelectorAll("li");
            var item = container.querySelector("li.selected");

            if (item) {
                textBox.value = item.textContent;
                textBox.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
            }

            items.forEach(function(item) {
                item.removeEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
                    setSelected(item);
                });

                item.removeEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
                    clearSelected(item);
                });
            });

            container.remove();
        }
    }

    function buildList(textBox, uniqueId) {
        var container = document.getElementById(uniqueId);

        if (!container) {
            var rect = textBox.getBoundingClientRect();
            var width = rect.width + 5
            var x = rect.left - 3;
            var y = rect.top + rect.height + 1;

            container = document.createElement("div");
            container.setAttribute("aria-label", textBox.getAttribute("aria-label"));
            container.setAttribute("id", uniqueId);
            container.classList.add("combo-drop-popup");
            container.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
            container.style.transition = 'height 0.25s ease';
            container.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            container.style.opacity = "1";
            container.style.zIndex = "1910887";
            container.style.border = "1px solid #c8c8c8";
            container.style.height = '0';
            container.style.width = width + "px";
            container.style.left = x + "px";
            container.style.top = y + "px";

            var pickList = getFibonacciList(textBox, container);

            container.appendChild(pickList);
            textBox.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(container);

            setTimeout(function() {
                container.style.height = "auto"
            }, 250);
        }
    }

    function addPickList(textBox, uniqueId) {
        if (textBox) {
            var arrow = textBox.parentNode.nextSibling

            arrow.style.marginLeft = textBox.offsetWidth - 23 + "px";
            arrow.style.marginTop = "3px";
            arrow.style.display = "block";

            if (!document.getElementById(uniqueId)) {
                textBox.addEventListener("focus", function() { buildList(textBox, uniqueId); });
                textBox.addEventListener("blur", function() { clearList(textBox, uniqueId); });
                arrow.addEventListener("click", function() { buildList(textBox, uniqueId); });
            };
        }
    }

    function isPbiEditor() {
        var isPbiEditor = false;
        var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");

        for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            var anchor = anchors[i];
            if (anchor.href.startsWith("http://host/collection/project/_workitems/edit/")) {
                if (anchor.textContent.startsWith("Product Backlog Item")) {
                    isPbiEditor = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return isPbiEditor;
    }

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        var effort = document.querySelector("input[aria-label='Effort']");
        var value = document.querySelector("input[aria-label='Business Value']");

        for (var mutation of mutations) {
            if (mutation.type === "childList") {
                if (isPbiEditor()) {
                    addPickList(effort, "58KJ76F");
                    addPickList(value, "37L9Q9P");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the datatype for the custom field to picklist and the underlying datatype to text or integer.

That way you can provide a list of values to select from.

As an alternative, there are [a number of custom picklist controls available on the Azure DevOps Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=control&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Boards&sortBy=Relevance). These can be used to databind a field to a REST API or different datatypes etc.

If needed you can hide the existing field and put a new control on the form.

Comment: *"If needed you can hide the existing field and put a new control on the form."* I did consider that, but it has to be the Effort field as it's used in other calculations across the project. No changing the datatype for that one. I'll have a look through those extensions, thanks.